# Problem with compound Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $X_k$ for $k=1,2,...$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mu_k=0$ and $\sigma_k^2=1$ for all $k$. Consider de random process $$S(t)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N(t)}X_k $$
where $N(t)$ is a Poisson process of mean $\lambda t$ and independent from $X_k\forall k$.

With this information, I have to calculate the autocorrelation

$$R(S(t_1),S(t_2))=\mathbb{E}[S(t_1)S(t_2)],t_2>t_1$$

So far, I've done this:

$$\mathbb{E}[S(t_1)S(t_2)]=\mathbb{E}[S(t_1)\cdot (S(t_2)+S(t_1)-S(t_1))]=\mathbb{E}[S^2(t_1)]+\mathbb{E}[S(t_1)(S(t_2)-S(t_1))]$$

The doubt I have is if the last term can be divided into the product of two expectations. I'm not sure if $S(t_1)$ and $S(t_2)-S(t_1)$ are independent from each other. Are they? If not, how can I solve this?

Comment: They are indeed independent. The compound Poisson process is a Lévy process and hence has independent increments (over non-overlapping time intervals). Note that $S(t_2)-S(t_1)$ is the increment over $[t_1,t_2]$ and $S(t_1)$ the increment over $[0,t_1]$.

Comment: I'm confused because $S(t_2)-S(t_1)=\sum\limits_{k=N(t_1)+1}^{N(t_2)}X_k$, so it apparently depends on $N(t_1)$ as it is the inferior limit of that sum. Wouldn't that interfere with its independence with $S(t_1)$?

Comment: $S(t_2)-S(t_1)$ depends on $t_2-t_1$, not $t_1$.